# Iterating over integer arrays with fixed sum in Julia

Tags: algorithm, iterator, julia

I am looking for an algorithm to iterate over all arrays of length n whose entries are integers between 0 and d and whose sum is k*d. It would be even better if there is a way to do this with built-in Julia functions and iterators. The algorithm should be non-recursive and memory efficient as I am hoping to use this for reasonable values of n.

For small values of n, d, and k, I've written down all such arrays in lexicographical ordering, but I haven't been able to come up with code for iterating through all such arrays.

Comment: "built-in Julia" (do you mean only functions in `Base`?) is an odd restriction... Regardless, you appear to want a constrained variant of `partitions(n, m)` from [Combinatorics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl). `partitions` returns an iterator object, but you would need to instantiate the arrays to test your conditions (I think), which won't be efficient. I suspect the solution is a custom implementation of `partitions` that incorporates your constraints. Hopefully a dev from that package shows up, because it looks very non-trivial to me!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'd love to use any existing Julia code, not limited to `Base`. Yes, I agree it looks very similar to `partitions(n,m)` but with the added sum constraint. I'm not sure how to handle it. Perhaps I'll look inside the Combinatorics.jl package more to see how `partitions(n,m)` is coded.

Comment: This is not an easy combinatorics question. And the solution has something to do with Catalan numbers and permutations of Catalan arrangements. Hmm interesting problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work but it requires `Combinatorics.jl` and `ResumableFunctions.jl`

```
using Combinatorics, ResumableFunctions
@resumable function gen_all(n, k, d)
    for x in partitions(k*d + n, n)
        x = x .- 1
        if all(x .<= d) 
            ys = Set(permutations(x))
            for y in ys
                @yield y
            end
        end
    end
end


for ga in gen_all(5, 2, 2)
    println(ga)
end
```

gives

```
[2, 0, 0, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: wonderful, thanks! This seems to work, let me test it on a few examples. Can you provide some description of your code? For instance, what is it doing and why?

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw read thsi twitter thread https://twitter.com/dzj_evalparse/status/1107964924024635392 I have given an overview of the algorithm. Please accept this as the answer if it works for a few examples.

Comment: I think there might be a more efficient way of doing this, but I haven't had time to figure it out. So I'll accept your answer (thanks!) and will post another solution if the more efficient way ends up being correct.